# Moment generating function of $(W_T, \max W_t)$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, moment-generating-functions

Does there exist an explicit formula for the moment generating function $\psi(u, v) = E e^{u W_T + v M_T}$ of the pair $(W_T, M_T)$ where $M_T = \max_{0\leq t\leq T} W_t$?

Using the well-known pdf of the pair, the mgf can be expressed as

$$\psi(u,v)
= \int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y \exp\left(u x + v y\right) \frac{2(2y-x)}{\sqrt{2\pi T^3}}\exp\left(-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2T}\right) dx dy$$

**Answer:**

Using the expression of $\psi$ above and the change of variable $z = 2y-x$, I managed to get the following expression from Wolfram Alpha:

\begin{align}
\psi(u,v) &=2\Phi\left(\sqrt{T}(u+v)\right) e^{\frac{1}{2}T(u+v)^2}\frac{u+v}{2u+v}\\
&\quad+\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{T}v}{2}\right) e^{\frac{1}{8}Tv^2}\left(\frac{2u e^{\frac{1}{4}Tu(2u+v)}}{2u+v}-1\right)
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function.

To make this work, I had to first calculate the inner integral (after changing variables) using Wolfram Alpha, and then calculate the outer integral. Finally, the result was expressed in terms of the error function instead of $\Phi$, so I had to rewrite that myself.

Note that Wolfram Alpha was not able to calculate the integrals directly. Instead, I had to first calculate the indefinite integral, and then apply the limits myself. Also, I calculated some of the integrals one summand at a time, though I don't know if that was necessary.

**Update:**
The "answer" I stated previously was wrong. The new answer is double-checked and correct. It is much nicer to look at as well.:)

Comment: The joint density of $(W_T,M_T)$ is known, did you apply it?

Comment: @Did I tried that, yes. But calculating that double integral (if it's even possible) is not trivial. I was hoping someone might be able to tell me that this had already been done.:)

Comment: Then add to the question the joint density and the integral you tried to compute.

Comment: And now use the change of variable $(x,y)\to(z,y)=(2y-x,y)$.

Comment: Of course! That did it. Using Wolfram Alpha I got it expressed in terms of the error function. I will add the answer to my post, for future reference.

Comment: @torbonde If you don't mind, can you add what did you exactly feed to Wolfram Alpha? Thanks.

Comment: @ir7 Yeah, I just did that. Sort of. If you check my calculations and find any mistakes, please let me know.

Comment: @ir7 My answer was wrong. I lost a constant somewhere. The new result is correct.

Comment: @torbonde It looks nicer. One thing you can do, if you want, is to add the mgf's  for $v=0$, and $u=0$, respectively, computed (known) separately, so that readers can see the consistency.